# How to detect iOS Screen is OLED?

Tags: ios, screen

On LED Screens it is quite common to use an off black (almost black). But on iPhone X' OLED screen this feels not the way to go. Pure black is what I want.

Is there a way to detect if the screen is an OLED type? (Rather than check if it is an iPhone X)

Also is there a way to distinguish the screen type within the Storyboard?

Comment: No & No, unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send `displayConfiguration` message to `mainScreen` instance of `UIScreen` and get access to the `FBSDisplayConfiguration` struct, but I'm not sure, that this code will be approved if you send it to the App Store:

```
UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"displayConfiguration");
id displayConfiguration = [mainScreen performSelector:selector];
```

Here is `displayConfiguration` for my iPhone SE:

```
<FBSDisplayConfiguration: 0x1c417fec0; Main; mode: "320x568@2x 60Hz sRGB SDR"> {
    CADisplay.name = LCD;
    CADisplay.deviceName = primary;
    CADisplay.seed = 2;
    tags = 0;
    currentMode = <FBSDisplayMode: 0x1c4094d70; 320x568@2x (640x1136/2) 60Hz sRGB SDR>;
    safeOverscanRatio = {0.89999997615814209, 0.89999997615814209};
    nativeCenter = {320, 568};
    pixelSize = {640, 1136};
    bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}};
    CADisplay = <CADisplay:LCD primary>;
}
```

[It seems](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/CADisplay.h) that `CADisplay` is also a part of private API.

PS: I don't have ability to test these code on the iPhone X, if you have—please, let me know which is value of `CADisplay.name`. I'm interesting too :)

Comment: Nice try :) ... my iPhone X FBSDisplayConfiguration
<FBSDisplayConfiguration: 0x1c8168d00; Main; mode: "375x812@3x 60Hz p3 SDR"> {
    CADisplay.name = LCD;
    CADisplay.deviceName = primary;
    CADisplay.seed = 2;
    tags = 0;
    currentMode = <FBSDisplayMode: 0x1c8095b30; 375x812@3x (1125x2436/3) 60Hz p3 SDR>;
    safeOverscanRatio = {0.89999997615814209, 0.89999997615814209};
    nativeCenter = {562.5, 1218};
    pixelSize = {1125, 2436};
    bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 812}};
    CADisplay = <CADisplay:LCD primary>;
}